# USB 3.1 ports is recognized as USB 3.0 in ArchLinux

Tags: drivers, usb

My PC is built on ASUS Z170i. It has two USB 3.1 Gen2 / 10 Gbit/s ports. 
The port is showed as a USB 3.0 port and speed of this port is 5000 M. 
How to make this port displayed/running in USB 3.1 Gen2 / 10 Gbit/s mode in Linux?

Output of `lsusb'. It showed the speed is 5000M, which is USB 3.0 speed.

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 9: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Bus 04 is the USB 3.1 port.

Here is from `dmseg`. It said SuperSpeed.

```
[    1.554071] xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.554073] xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.554074] xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.554093] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    1.554104] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.02
[    1.554104] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.554105] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.554106] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH xhci-hcd
[    1.554106] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:06:00.0
[    1.554258] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.554263] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
```

And here is from `lspci -v`

```
06:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
```

Last is the output of `lsusb -vv -s 4:1`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.02
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.2.9-arch1-1-ARCH xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:06:00.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x002b
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat           0 micro seconds
  SuperSpeedPlus USB Device Capability:
    bLength                28
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType     10
    bmAttributes         0x00000023
      Sublink Speed Attribute count 3
      Sublink Speed ID count 1
    wFunctionalitySupport   0x0001
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[0]   0x00050034
      Speed Attribute ID: 4 5Gb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[1]   0x000500b4
      Speed Attribute ID: 4 5Gb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[2]   0x000a4035
      Speed Attribute ID: 5 10Gb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeedPlus
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[3]   0x000a40b5
      Speed Attribute ID: 5 10Gb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeedPlus
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

My question is how to make this port work in 10 Gb/s mode? Or display this port as a SuperSpeed+.

Comment: what is your interface configuration? what router do you have? does the router support 10g?

Comment: USB port speed.

Comment: Has your Linux kernel got USB 3.1 support?  I believe the initial USB 3.1 was added in Linux kernel version 4.6.

Comment: I think it should support. Here is the version. 5.2.11-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 29 08:09:36 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Downgrade kernel to 5.0 can fix this issue.

Comment: I had the same issue with Debian 10. Solved by using the unstable repository to install kernel 5.3.0. There appears to be a bug in the kernel that has been fixed in 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I have four ideas:

1. Commercial USB3 names are very confused; now, ever more thanks to USB3.2 **[1]**! For this reason kernel simply bad names controller.
2. Another confusion issue: 10Gbit doubles its rate thanks doubling lane used **[2]**. Kernel shows `5000M` but it's just per-lane.
3. BIOS/EFI could disable it, maybe for backward compatibility.
4. Linux kernel does not well support your USB chipset.

**Long story short**, please do a benchmark/test for check **real** connection speed!

---

**[1]** https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2019/2/27/18243425/usb-3-2-standard-names-connectivity-cables-innovators-forum
**[2]** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#3.2